# TypeError 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, string, python-re

```
import re
p = re.compile("ca.e")
def print_match(m):
if m:
    print("m.group():", m.group()) 
    print("m.string:", m.string()) 
    print("m.start():", m.start()) 
    print("m.end():", m.end()) 
    print("m.span():", m.span()) 
else:
    print("No Match")

m = p.match("case") 
print_match(m)
```

I don't understand why print("m.string:", m.string()) and print_match(m) are not callable...

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects)

> ## Match.string
>
> The string passed to `match()` or `search()`.

`Match.string` is a simple slot or property defined on the object, not a method. It's either declared in the constructor as

```
def __init__(self, ...):
    self.string = ...
```

or as an explicit property like

```
@property
def string(self):
    ...
```

And neither is a conventional Python method, so neither warrants calling like one.